# when pressed the spinner drop down, full screen mode disabled

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I am using Java for an android project, since i have to use the application in full screen mode, when i pressed the drop down menu (spinner), full screen mode is disabled. do you have any options to prevent this? even i press the drop down, i don't want to exit the full screen.
i have went through all the options including

```
//method for full screen
private void hideSystemUI() {

    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE

                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}

  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Main_Menu.this,
                R.layout.custom_spinner, paths);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_spinner_drop_down_item);
        btnlanguage.setAdapter(adapter);


        btnlanguage.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {

                //   Toast.makeText(Main_Menu.this, urlinformation.HomeURL(btnlanguage.getSelectedItem().toString(), slug), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mywebview.loadUrl(urlinformation.HomeURL(btnlanguage.getSelectedItem().toString(), slug));

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution, put this method in your code and call the method onCreate after adding data to spinner.

```
   public static void apply(Spinner spinner) {
    try {
        Field listPopupField = Spinner.class.getDeclaredField("mPopup");
        listPopupField.setAccessible(true);
        Object listPopup = listPopupField.get(spinner);
        if (listPopup instanceof ListPopupWindow) {
            Field popupField = ListPopupWindow.class.getDeclaredField("mPopup");
            popupField.setAccessible(true);
            Object popup = popupField.get((ListPopupWindow) listPopup);
            if (popup instanceof PopupWindow) {
                ((PopupWindow) popup).setFocusable(false);
            }
        }
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update for Appcompact Spinner Java. Make sure imports are correct for this to work

```
    public static void avoidSpinnerDropdownFocus(AppCompatSpinner spinner) {
    try {

        if(spinner instanceof AppCompatSpinner){
            
        Field listPopupField = AppCompatSpinner.class.getDeclaredField("mPopup");
        listPopupField.setAccessible(true);
        Object listPopup = listPopupField.get(spinner);

        if (listPopup instanceof androidx.appcompat.widget.ListPopupWindow) {

            Field popupField = androidx.appcompat.widget.ListPopupWindow.class.getDeclaredField("mPopup");
            popupField.setAccessible(true);
            Object popup = popupField.get(listPopup);


            if (popup instanceof PopupWindow) {
                ((PopupWindow) popup).setFocusable(false);
            }
        }
        }

     } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```